# Download Android Support v4 Jar Revision 9 (!)

Tags: android, android-support-library

Revision 10 is the newest Android Support Library, but its bugged, so I can't use it. 
Where can I download Revision 9?

I need the .jar from Revision 9, because on Revision 10 the Notification on Android 3 and 3.1 are bugged. I "hacked" the Rev10 to work, but the ViewPagerIndicator don't like it and don't work (my project don't compile anymore) with this .jar. Now I search the rev9 jar.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "its bugged" -- citation, please.

Comment: Notifications on API Level 13 are causing a force close. Just search it on b.android.com, you'll find many opened issues. For example: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=36502

Comment: Make the code change outlined in that issue and rebuild the JAR, since the source code is already on your hard drive. Or use the patched JAR linked to in the issue. Or, use `NotificationBuilder2`, as outlined in that issue. Or, wait a few days for the next version of the Android Support package.

Comment: I solved my problems. I just clone the git repo from ViewPagerIndicator again and it worked. Weird issue ...

Comment: @CommonsWare for many of us, "wasting time fixing somethign that wasn't broken" isn't viable, when a simple download link would solve our problems instantly (I came here from google, looking for direct download link, so its sad that this answer doesn't have it)

Comment: @Adam What are you searching?

Comment: Direct download for the library (because Google refuses to reveal the "secret" URL) - and the install location for it. Google pointed to this question as one of the few good hits

Comment: @Adam Which library? r10 and r9 are below (r11 is the newest). You can also download them in the android sdk (they are located in: {sdk path}/extras/android/support).

Comment: I need the official download links (work won't allow me to use 3rd party hosted links for obvious reasons) :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who are searching, here is a download [link to a fixed r10](http://code.google.com/p/yuku-android-util/source/browse/ActionBarSherlock4/libs/android-support-v4.jar) and [a r9](https://github.com/Leandros/AndroidSupportLibrary/blob/master/android-support-v4_v9.jar) (I know, I missuse GitHub as download server).