# I am trying to setup "action bar's Up/Home button" on my other activities but I keep getting an error "NavUtils". How can I solve this?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

// this is code on my other activities

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
    case android.R.id.home:
         NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
```

//NavUtil show error
//suggests creating another class

```
        return true;
        }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Comment: what is the error? do you have some a `NavUtils` class in your project?

Comment: well ok then there is your problem obviously

Comment: How would a NavUtills class look like?

Comment: I have no idea it is not an Android API so whatever example you are going from is where you should look

Comment: [The NavUtils class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NavUtils.html) is part of the [Android v4 Support Library](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v4), which you need to [add to your project](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html)

Answer (score -2):

Make sure you have latest Android.support.v4.jar added to your lib files.

Also there are a few known issues with this files. See the link below:

[Download Android Support v4 Jar Revision 9 (!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13324372/download-android-support-v4-jar-revision-9)

Comment: have downloaded the zip file but I still do not know how to use in the project am working on. Do you have some guides on how to use it?

Comment: copy the jar file in libs folder. Eclipse should pick it up as soon as you will do refresh on your project. You should also be able to see it under Properties->Java Build Path->libraries